# Check what Gutenberg blocks are in post_content

Tags: post-content, block-editor

I'm working on a design that has different styling if a certain Gutenberg block is present on a page. In other words, if the first block is a custom built Gutenberg block, the post_title is rendered elsewhere due to design choices made.

Is there any function in WordPress to get a list of all Gutenberg blocks present in the post_content?

Comment: There is a website https://whichblocks.com/ When you type a web page url, it scans the page and find out which gutenberg blocks is used in the page.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

WordPress 5.0+ has a function for this: `parse_blocks()`. To see if the first block in the post is the Heading block, you'd do this:

```
$post = get_post(); 

if ( has_blocks( $post->post_content ) ) {
    $blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );

    if ( $blocks[0]['blockName'] === 'core/heading' ) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find this function.
Funnily enough my custom code does basically the same thing but with a whole lot less code! Anyhow, marked as accepted as it's the proper built-in function.

Comment: This function has been deprecated (but only renamed), you should use `has_blocks($blockName)` instead: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/pull/8631/commits/7e5efa2bcfa02c970a9bf0955e04a34a532157e7. There's also `has_block()` (without "s").

Comment: @NicoPrat we've updated the answer to reflect correct methods

Comment: Bear in mind there is a known issue at the moment where `parse_blocks()` returns non-existent blocks as NULL array elements - https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45312

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/parse_blocks/ :)

Answer (score 2):

The solution I'm using as of writing check the post_content for the Gutenberg HTML comments. Due to future Gutenberg changes this might not work in the future.

```
<?php    
$post_content = get_the_content( get_the_ID() ); // Get the post_content
preg_match_all('<!-- /wp:(.*?) -->', $post_content, $blocks); // Get all matches in between <!-- /wp: --> strings

// $blocks[1] contains the names of all the blocks present in the post_content
if ( in_array( 'heading', $blocks[1] ) ) {
    // Post content contains a wp:heading block
}
else {
    // Post content does not contain a wp:heading block
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of the release of 5.0 these functions have been deprecated with Gutenberg now integrated into the core.  I imagine, but have not confirmed that these functions still exist in the Gutenberg standalone plugin.

Instead of `gutenberg_content_has_blocks` use `has_blocks`

Instead of `gutenberg_parse_blocks` use `parse_blocks`

Comment: @JeffreyvonGrumbkow thing is, ian-hoyte has to low rep to edit or comment =)