# How to check if post has Video or Gallery block in Gutenberg blocks?

Tags: block-editor

I need to get information on front page about post - if it has gallery or video or both, how to find this information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check what Gutenberg blocks are in post\_content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/310301/check-what-gutenberg-blocks-are-in-post-content)

Comment: @JacobPeattie, thanks for the link. The current question here can be solved with `has_block()` so I decided to answer it here, as it would not answer the question in [Check what Gutenberg blocks are in post_content](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/310301/check-what-gutenberg-blocks-are-in-post-content) as that question seems to be how to determine the first block type of a post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can use the built-in [`has_block( $block_type, $post )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_block/) function to check for specific blocks.

The first input argument is the block type in `<!-- wp:{$block_type} -->` and the second one is the post object.

To find the corresponding block type, we can view it in the *Code Editor* view via the shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>

or via the settings:

[image: code view]

For example the gallery block will show as:

[image: Code view]

**Example: Within The Loop**

Checking for `wp:gallery` and `wp:video` blocks, within the loop, the corresponding block types are `gallery` and `video`:

```
if ( has_block( 'video' ) && has_block( 'gallery' ) ) {
   // ...
}
```

**Example: Outside The Loop**

For a given post object, we can use the second input argument of `has_block()` to determince if the post contains the `wp:gallery` and `wp:video` blocks:

```
$mypost = get_post( 123 );

if ( has_block( 'video', $mypost ) && has_block( 'gallery', $mypost ) ) {
   // ...
}
```

**Example: Custom Block Within The Loop**

Checking the content for a custom block with namespace: `<!-- wp:custom/block -->`, it would be:

```
if ( has_block( 'custom/block' ) ) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I found my problem why I asked this question:

if ( has_block( 'core-embed/vimeo' ) || has_block( 'core-embed/youtube') || has_block( 'video' )) {
// ...
}

I was placing youtube video and "has_block( 'video' )" doesn't recognises that.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. In the example here above we assumed the video to be uploaded to the site and added via the `wp:video` block. To check if one has the `wp:core-embed/youtube` block one can use `has_block( 'core-embed/youtube' )`, To find the corresponding block type, one can switch to the code editor view with the  `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+M` shortcut or via the settings.